# highchart issue in [object,Object] in laravel

Tags: laravel, highcharts, laravel-8

please help highchart display data like [object Object]
Is there something wrong in making the code or is there something that needs to be configured?
[display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGSai.jpg)

json respon
"[{"CUSTOMER":"ARVEOLI"},{"CUSTOMER":"SETIAP HARI DIPAKAI ( EVERMOS )"},{"CUSTOMER":"BANK MANDIRI"},{"CUSTOMER":"KAMPUNG MARKETERINDO BERDAYA PT / COD"},{"CUSTOMER":"PASAR KARUHUN "},{"CUSTOMER":"PALUGADA"},{"CUSTOMER":"TOKOTALK"},{"CUSTOMER":"AZERO"},{"CUSTOMER":"BANK RAKYAT INDONESIA PT/R(KK)"},{"CUSTOMER":"CADAS STORE"}] ◀"

Comment: I think you should share some more information (some code for example), so someone can actually help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: in controller 
` $customer = DB::table('ticket_table')
        ->select('CUSTOMER')
        ->groupBy('CUSTOMER')
        ->orderByRaw('COUNT(USER_ID) DESC')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();`

in chart {!! json_encode ($jumlahcustomer)!!}

Comment: It's hard to understand your issue. Do you use provided JSON as a `series.data`? In that case, the format is wrong. Take a look at the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data . Otherwise, please reproduce your issue in the working demo. You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z0dbphsq/

Answer (score 0):

in controller
 `$customer = DB::table('ticket_table') ->select('CUSTOMER') ->groupBy('CUSTOMER') ->orderByRaw('COUNT(USER_ID) DESC') ->limit(10) ->get();`

in chart {!! json_encode ($jumlahcustomer)!!}